# How can I change post array value to allow insertion as Unique IDs (columns) mysql

Tags: mysqli, jquery-cloneya

```
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO  mytable...

        `friends`,
        `friend1`,
        `friend2`,
        `friend3`,                                          
                VALUES (NULL,   '$friends',
                                '$friends[0]'
                                '$friends[1]'
                                '$friends[2]'
```

Using cloneya.js to duplicate fields, I get an array value for a set of 3 names. Posting to mysql, I get three names in the in the first field(friends) but only the first,second and third letter of the first name in the subsequent fields (friend1-3).  How can I insert each name to the separate fields?

Answer (score 0):

`$friends` is not an array in your case, its just a string. Which means that `$friends[0]` will be the first character of that string, `$friends[1]` will be the second character and so on. You must send the friends with a different variable name so you have `$friends` which is a string and `$otherName` as an array which you can use in your sql query.

Keep in mind to use prepared statements when you use sql queries which depends on variables. Also convert your tables to 3NF.